# How to multiply a number by a function passed by reference

Tags: c++, function, parameters, typedef

I have the following code above my main method and all my other functions:

```
typedef double (*FUNC)(double);

double integrate(FUNC f, double a, double b){
double sum = 0;
for(int i=a; i<=b; i++){
    sum = sum + (f * .0001); //error occurs here, red squiggly line under "f"
}
    return sum;
}
```

In the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compiler, I get an error: Expression must have arithmetic or enum type. I pointed out where the error comes from above in a comment. Can someone explain to me why I have this error and how I can resolve this error?

Comment: afaik you can't pass functions by reference, there are only functionpointers, and that is what you are using. (the by reference part could be considered calling a function driectly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this instead

```
 sum = sum + f(.0001);
```

Multiplying a function pointer by a fraction would not go so well.

Comment: So, I can't multiply a function that returns x^2 by a number between 0 and 1?

Comment: Sure you can, but you can't multiply the function-pointer itself with a number. Remember that *f* is just a pointer to the function which does something with the double it is passed. You have to invoke the function to get something useful. So if you had a variable x available, you would instead to `sum = sum + f(x) * 0.0001`.

Answer (score 3):

I take it you are trying to integrate `f(x)` for values of `x` from `a` to `b`?

In which case your code is quite incorrect.

Your 0.0001 seems to indicate that you are actually trying to use 10000 steps, in which case you would use something along the lines of:

```
const int steps = 10000;
double x = a;
double delta = (b - a) / steps;
for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++, x += delta)
```

You would then calculate use a call `f(x)` to call the function pointer, and sum that up.

Comment: you spotted another likely mistake but did not awnser the core of the question, about the function pointer. Add that to make it a great awnser